# Securely send sensitive token to SNS for use in Lambda

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I need to send an AWS Lambda function a key and secret for another service. I could just bake the key/secret into the function but then I have to republish the Lambda functions when/if they change and that seems undesirable.

I am triggering my Lambda function via SNS. So my workflow would be:

- Prepare Payload
- Publish Payload to SNS Topic
- Lambda Runs receiving payload,
- Lambda uses key/secret provided in payload to perform necessary actions on another API

I assume the SNS publish is done over HTTPS so `Server -> SNS topic` would be encrypted.

What I have not seen specifically called out is the transfer from `SNS -> Lambda`. Again I can assume it's done securely but I was looking for verification.

My other option, which I have seen done in the AWS Lambda Example for a Slack Echo Service is using `AWS Key Management` for encrypting and decrypting. For example, using python:

```
kms = boto3.client('kms')
key = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob = b64decode(event["key"]))['Plaintext']
secret = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob = b64decode(event["secret"]))['Plaintext']
```

Would using `Key Management Encryption Services` be overkill/even necessary here or can I just send the payload and let HTTPS handle it?

**OR**

Should I be publicly flogged for even thinking of sending something like a key/secret over `SNS -> Lambda` and instead should bake it into the Lambda function itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the question about SNS->Lambda encryption. I would assume, like you, that is is over HTTPS but I think you would need to contact AWS support to get confirmation of that.

As to your other question, I think KMS is actually a good fit for this and not necessarily overkill. Another option you might consider is storing the key in DynamoDB. I've also seen people suggest storing Lambda configuration data like this in S3.

Comment: Also just found this other answer echoing yours: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-ways-to-store-configuration-properties-for-AWS-Lambda-functions.  Thank You!